# estimateRigidTransform missing from 3.5+

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I have moved from 3.4 to 4.0 and cv2 is missing the estimateRigidTransform function. The documentation shows it is still there in the C++ library but it is not in cv2. Has it been renamed or am I missing something stupid when im building it?

I checked 3.5 and it looks like it is the first version where it is missing.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the doc, [`estimateRigidTransform`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga762cbe5efd52cf078950196f3c616d48) is now deprecated.

You should use [`estimateAffine2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga27865b1d26bac9ce91efaee83e94d4dd) or [`estimateAffinePartial2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gad767faff73e9cbd8b9d92b955b50062d)

Also, I'm pretty sure that OpenCV 3.5 does not exists: you go from 3.4.4 to 4.0.0.

Comment: Apologies, I meant 4.0, I shouldn't be coding tired. Thanks for the help!

Comment: shape of anchor = (1280, 1920), shape of img = (1280, 1920) and new_t = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(img, anchor, fullAffine=False)                                         How should I replace estimateRigidTransofrm  with estimateAffine2d?                                I used cv2.estimateAffine2d(img, anchor, fullAffine=False)  and received error. OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/ptsetreg.cpp:831: error: (-215:Assertion failed) count >= 0 && to.checkVector(2) == count in function 'estimateAffine2D'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the estimateAffine3D as follows:

```
cv::Mat get_rigid_transform(std::vector<cv::points3d> poinst1 , std::vector<cv::points3d> points2)
{

   cv::Mat affine_transformation = cv::Mat::eye(3, 4, CV_64F);
   std::vector<uchar> inliers;
   cv::estimateAffine3D(points1, poinst2, affine_transformation, inliers);
   return affine_transformation;
}
```